# Using Python Shell in Bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line, autocomplete

I want to use python shell in bash (i.e., executing $ python and hitting enter in bash), but I've noticed several things missing that would boost my productivity.

Are there any known resources that fixes any (or all) of these issues?

1) no autoindent

When I hit enter after writing

`>>> for i in [1, 2]:`

bash does not indent 4 spaces automatically

2) weird command line history

When I execute a multiline command:

```
>>> for i in [1, 2]:
...     pass
...
```

and I hit the up-arrow to get my history, instead of getting the entire multiline command I get

`...     pass`

3) no syntax coloring

4) no autocomplete

Comment: That’s just how it works, it’s a simple tool. Have you considered using python’s built-in editor? Try typing “idle” in terminal. Also, can you add why you want to code in terminal? I normally just do some quick stuff there, but nothing too complex. You also have tools such as repl.it for just messing around.

Comment: Are you asking for something like the IPython shell?

Comment: bash isn't involved in this. After you run the `python` command (in bash, or zsh, or csh, or whatever shell you happen to use) you're talking directly to python's [read-eval-print loop (REPL)](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/repl/). You shell doesn't get involved again until you edit python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at ipython. It is a much more functional python shell in the terminal. It can be installed with `pip install ipython` and started in the terminal by typing `ipython`. See the docs [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for more details.